# MSTest UnitTestingFramework 10.1 vs 10.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

I updated my reference for `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` in a test project from 10 to 10.1 and the expected exception doesn't seem to do it's job anymore.  Try this for example ...

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(FileNotFoundException))]
public void SanityTest()
{
    File.ReadAllLines("TheresNoWayThisThingExists");
}
```

Test fails.  If I revert back to 10 (have to undo), it passes.  Anyone verify this or is it just me?  I've tried it in resharper's test runner and ms test runner with the same result.

**edit : additional info**

It seems to know it passed ...sort of.  Adding in a string value for 'noExceptionMessage' does NOT return that string value on failure.

Also AllowDerivedTypes seems to have no effect as well.  (I swapped out FileNotFound to just Exception, same result)

Comment: Are your test annotations assembly and your test runner the same version? I'm not sure you can update one without the other, or at least I doubt you could reliably use 10.1 annotations with the 10.0 runner.

Answer (score 2):

It happens when a project runtime version is v4.0.30319 and you change MSTest UnitTestingFramework from 10 to 10.1 which is v2.0.50727. There is no UnitTestingFramework 10.1 with runtime version v4.0.30319. So in order to fix it you need either change runtime version of the project or switch back to UnitTestingFramework 10.